# MPDF is being output to browser as strange character string

Tags: laravel, pdf, mpdf

mPDF is being output to browser as strange character string like this

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => $format , 'orientation' => $orientation]);       
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,\Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HEADER_CSS);
$mpdf->WriteHTML(view($view,$data), \Mpdf\HTMLParserMode::HTML_BODY);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem, u need to adding some code `ob_get_clean();` before `$mpdf->Output();`  . And it there is weird character no more.